# Is the label silently ignored if a node name isn't provided?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It seems that this creates a node with label "User" and name "Steve", as expected.

```
create (u:User{id:2, name:"Steve"})
```

And this creates a node with name "Steve", but no label:

```
create (User{id:2, name:"Steve"})
```

if providing a variable name for the created node (`u:`) even when I don't refer to it later is required, fine. But it seems it's not required to be valid cypher, but for some reason in that case the label is silently ignored. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is a necessary prefix for a label:

```
create (User{id:2, name:"Steve"})
```

creates a node without labels having a symbolic name of `User` to be used later in the statement.

To set a label use:

```
create (:User{id:2, name:"Steve"})
```

This creates a node with a label of `User` but without a symbolic name, so you cannot refer to it in a subsequent part of the cypher statement.

```
create (u:User{id:2, name:"Steve"})
```

is the combination of both.

Comment: ahhh... so in the third example, `u` is the "symbolic name" and `User` is the variable, and in the absence of any `:`, it's only a symbolic name?